# Manipulating Database operation and Dictionary concept

Tags: android, dictionary

I am new in Android app development. Now I am writing a singleton class for manipulating database operation. In case of select query, I am planning to store the "table field name" as key and data of each row in a dictionary. Then each dictionary of row data is stored in an Array. I have implemented this concept in iOS. But as I am new to Android, I don't how the dictionary concept can be implemented in Android. Does this is available in Android? If so can anybody help me to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ios may be `dictionary` is save data as key/pair value

and in android we have `HashMap<Key,Value>`

```
Map<Intger,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

here `Integer is key and String is value`

**//Add data in map**

```
map.put(1,"string1");
map.put(2,"string2");
```

**NOTE ::**

Mind that `key is unique not allowed duplicates` and `if you need ordered data then use LinkedHashmap instead of Hashmap`

**//retrieve data**

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry :map.entrySet())
{
    int i = entry.getKey();
    String s = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: HashMap is in java and not in android

Comment: Thank you friend. Let me check it.

Comment: @sleimanjneidi android is not programming language and its java so why not ?

Comment: Can we use only integer as key. According to my need, the key should be the name of tablefields. Is it possible?